# How to set the position of 2nd div dynamically

Tags: css

I need little help from you in order to set the position of `div` dynamically.

I have two `div`s and I want to position 2nd `div` below the first one. Currently it is overlapping both of them. And my content of 1st `div` changes dynamically, how it could be possible. Please help. I believed, it could be done with `jQuery`, but not able to get idea how can I get the position of first div and set the next div position.

```
<div id="firstDiv">
</div>

<div id="secondDiv" style="position:absolute;">
</div>
```

Comment: for better understanding, will you please put your code in jsfiddle.

Comment: Post your html and css code here. (_related to this issue_).

Answer (score 0):

you asked for a jQuery solution, so:

```
var first_div_top = $("#top_div").offset().top;
var first_div_height = $("#top_div").height();
$("#bottom_div").top = first_div_top+first_div_height;
// or this
$("#bottom_div").css({
    "top":first_div_top+first_div_height
});
```

Comment: Not working. I found out the top has been set to 384px which still overlap the bottom half of the first div.

Comment: These are the values which I am getting, var first_div_top=78;var first_div_height=306px;

Comment: Did you run this code after the first div has been loaded?

Comment: Yes, even I am testing it with console. But I noticed that, when I hover the container for which I extracting the top and height property is itself half the dynamic content. Meaning that, the dynamic content exist inside a container but container itself cover half the dynamic content. What could be the possible reason?

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle.net with an example of the problem? or post the rendered html code +css after you load the first div? meanwhile see if maybe you accidentally somewhere manualy set the height of the first div, or if you are not sure, try adding a " `height:100% !important;` " to the first div, and dont forget the !important flag

Comment: It still not cover the dynamic region. Actually my first div is quite complex, I can't be able to post in jsfiddle. Any idea?

Comment: Without seeing your code its hard to say, you should go over all your files and search for anything that constraints your divs height, or you could try setting it to 100% using JavaScript after u init it's contents

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying position for element..Like specify position from left and top

```
#secondDiv{
position:absolute;
left:100px;/*your left position*/
top:150px;/*your top position*/
}
```